# AndroidManifest ошибка

Tags: android, xml

Не могу понять в чем проблема. Полное имя  с указанием папки не помогает.
При Нажатии ALT+ENTER появляется список как на 2 изображении.

[image: Где подчеркнута пишет:'class' or 'interface' expected.]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: «Полное имя пакета с указанием папки не помогает» – покажите, что Вы под этим подразумеваете.

Comment: Например: app.java.MainActivity.

Comment: А название пакета куда дели? Попробуйте так: `com.example.mmmaaatttt.MainActivity` (это для проекта, который на втором скриншоте).

Comment: Не помогло. Та же самая ошибка.

Comment: А если создать новый проект, ничего в нем не менять и сразу запустить. Появится ли эта ошибка?

Comment: Да. После перезапуска то же самое.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45001/discussion-between-romag-and-s8am).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте написать так:

```
<activity android:name = "com.example.imatematik02.Restart">

<activity android:name = "com.example.imatematik02.MenuActivity">
```